# fatal error: 'clang-c/Index.h' file not found on OSX 10.9.4

Tags: clang, llvm-clang

I was trying to install clang_complete on OSX 10.9.4. However while running make I get the following error:

```
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/clic_add.dir/clic_add.cpp.o
/Users/bharat/Desktop/clang_indexer/clic_add.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'clang-c/Index.h'
      file not found
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I have clang, llvm-g++ and llvm-gcc. How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can download source code for clang 
svn checkout http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk

The header should be in the include/clang-c folders, you can edit the cmake file and pass in the location of the header in the CPP flags (-I)

cmake file would be here:-
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/flags.make